# Passing data from windows form to usercontrol VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to get or transfer the data from the windows form to an usercontrol.
The variable "nform" is the the usercontrol UC_REQUEST

```
    Dim nform = New UC_REQUEST

    Dim lv As ListViewItem = nform.ListView2.Items.Add(cbBranch.Text)
    lv.SubItems.Add(lbParticular.Text)
    lv.SubItems.Add(lbID.Text)
    lv.SubItems.Add(txtAmount.Text)
    lv.SubItems.Add(txtRemarks.Text)
    lv.SubItems.Add(txtCredit.Text)
```

Comment: No, don't try to access internal controls of the user control in that way, Just create a class with all the data that you want to pass then create a method on the user control that receives an instance of that class. Finally inside the user control's method set the internal listview

Comment: Are you asking if your method is the 'correct' way to do it? I can't see any question being asked from your post.

Comment: yes, I am asking the correct way.

Comment: Thats not a good practice, I don't recommend you to do that.